# Regex convert text into "" lowercase

Tags: regex

I have to convert texts like

> Example "Example Text" to Example "example text"
>   
>   EXAMPLE "EXAMPLE TEXT" to EXAMPLE "example text"

could you help with regex doing this?

Comment: No need for any regex... what programming language?

Comment: I have only like 10000 plain text files

Answer (score 3):

```
\"[^\"]+\"
```

Then use a lowercase substitution mechanism.

In Regex101:

```
\"([^\"]+)\"

\L"$1"
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YY712i/1)

Answer (score 3):

If to put everything to lower, use:

```
\L$1
```

[See the Regex101 example.](https://regex101.com/r/6e836T/1)

`\L` is the lowercase transformation of

`$1` contents of the first group (only one group will be caught).

And, to catch only the text between quotation marks use:

```
"(.+?)"
```

Comment: I want change to lowercase only text in quotation marks

Comment: Sorry for the correction, I just want to be helpful, but this one fails depending on greediness. `"hi " dude" hello"` will be matched whole as a single match